# Is Google Play multiplayer p2p only?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer, leaderboard

I am implementing multiplayer android game. I am considering using some API to handle multiplayer. I decided to AppWarp and actually it works but I am afraid that game won't earn fo itself as this is paid service.

I've read about google multiplayer but I cannot find clear answer for my question. Is it P2P only or it's possible to configure it with server usage?

I am afraid of using P2P because of huge lags and that it can make the game unpleasant to play.

Bonus question:
Is it possible to set up leaderboard which i can treat as ranking (adding and subtracting points?). Or maybe some google cloud storage with some raw data which I would be able to update through some REST. I know that it exists but what are your experience with that? Can i treat it as some simple database where I would be able to store at least username and number of points which I would be able to add or subtract after winning or losing a match?

Maybe you know other services which you have experience with?

Comment: I guess u should read more on the Google Play Games API. It's all in there, and as far as I read, everything u want is possible there. Multiplayer including "game rooms" and servers, Leaderboards, the works

Comment: It doesn't help at all. I know it's there and it's not what I need. Have you read my whole question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from [**Real-time Multiplayer**](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#top_of_page), server usage plays a very important function in the design and implementation. One of these functions is:

> Stores participant and room state information on the Google Play games services servers during the lifecycle of the real-time multiplayer game.

Server usage was further discussed in the given concepts related to the typical lifecycle of a real-time multiplayer game given in [Real-time multiplayer game basics](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#real-time_multiplayer_game_basics).

[**Leaderboards**](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards), on the other hand, is possible to set it up and treat it as ranking among your players. As mentioned in the documentation:

> Leaderboards can be a fun way to drive competition among your players, both for your most hardcore fans (who will be fighting for the top spot in a public leaderboard) and for your more casual players (who will be interested in comparing their progress to their friends').

For more information, it will really be helpful to go through the given documentations.

In addition to that, I think the given technical and design solution given in this Stack post - [Mobile Multiplayer games and coping with high latency](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58450/mobile-multiplayer-games-and-coping-with-high-latency) will also help you.

Comment: I am not a beginner with using such technologies. I've read documentation of GP and I am asking for opinion from someone who used it in his games. The question is: Is multiplayer only P2P and is there a leaderboard where points can be subtracted.